# adb forward not working

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

adb port forwarding is not working for me and your insight is appreciated.
The following command is what I am trying

./adb forward tcp:5985 tcp:5984"

I don't see any errors(in logcat) but it just fails silently.  When I try the following command 
`curl localhost:5985` after that, I get "curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer"

When I try `curl localhost:5984`, I do see a message as I have a process running on port 5984 (Couchbase server).

I don't think this is an issue with adb itself as all other adb commands are working.  Amongst other things I have tried are
a) kill-server followed by start-server (with sudo mode as well)
b) Restarting my machine.

Needless to say, neither of these have worked.  I am working on x64 Ubuntu 11.10.

Please note that I am working with the emulator and my emulator device is running.
I do see other messages in logcat just not this one.

Thanks

-Venu

Comment: Where are you typing those commands? What you did is to forward PC port 5985 to android port 5984.

Comment: @Mister Smith  `adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote`

Answer (score 3):

Have you read this document from Google?
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging

It explains that you have to first make sure you can see your device with

```
adb devices
```

Then in Chrome on your Android device, go to Open Settings > Advanced > Developer tools and check the Enable USB Web debugging option as shown here:

[image]

Then enter the follow command:

```
adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote
```

And go to this URL in Chrome on your desktop:

```
localhost:9222
```

Does that work?

Comment: Also the desktop browser should be chrome.

Comment: I guess this is good if you're on android 4+ and have chrome for android.

Answer (score 2):

On the original question , the answer is to make sure your device emulator is running. On Ubuntu you can use: netstat -tan to see the TCP ports that your development machine is listening on.  Usually the port is 5554.  When the emulator is not started, there will not be a process listening on this port.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally got there. I'm not sure which one of these finally fixed the issue (but most are helpful):

- ensuring that `/etc/udev/rules.d/##-android.rules` was `chmod a+rw` so that we don't need to `sudo adb` and can edit it again
- On Ubuntu 12.04 the `ATTRS{idVendor}` is the simple 4 hex code (some pages will encourage you to take the full `lsusb` ####:#### code
- I now do not have the `SYMLINK+="android_adb"` entry in udev
- `adb devices` still shows `????????????` instead of my device code (but works now)
- `adb shell` actually returns a `#` prompt
- `adb usb` breaks it (it was not returning with `curl` which I thought was an improvement on the error, but no - it breaks it worse)

Comment: probable bad USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bug in adb forward](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65399643), such that small, fast data connections are simply dropped:

```
 emulator> nc -lk 9998
 host> adb forward tcp:9900 tcp:9998
 host> date | nc localhost 9900    # Does not arrive at the emulator
 host> ( date ; sleep 0.1 ) | nc localhost 9900  # Does arrive at the emulator
```

That said, when I try the above with `curl`, that data gets through - presumably because `curl` holds the socket open in the same way that `(date ; sleep 0.1)` does.

Answer (score 0):

This issue started happening for me when I updated Android SDK Platform Tools from version 29.0.2 to 29.0.3

I followed this [How to downgrade my SDK version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555337/how-to-downgrade-my-sdk-version)

Basically, you need to downgrade Android SDK Platform Tools to version 29.0.2:

1. Find your Android SDK folder
2. Rename platform-tools to platform-tools-29-0-3 (incase something goes wrong)
3. Download Android SDK Platform Tools 29.0.2 for your machine e.g. http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r29.0.2-windows.zip
4. Extract it into your Android/SDK folder
5. And you are done