# Exception when try to execute jobb command

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I've just update my Android SDK Tools to rev. 22.6 and I experimented this strange error when I try to create obb file (Android APK Expansion Files)

when executing in shell:

```
jobb
```

(yes, jast "joob") I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/waldheinz/fs/BlockDevice
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.waldheinz.fs.BlockDevice
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

with rev. 22.5 works well. Tried on Ubuntu and Windows8

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New revision 22.6.1 solve the problem.

Thanks to Ren and darrenp for good tempornay workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I just had exactly the same problem after upgrading to revision 22.6. So that I could continue my work, I decided to revert to an earlier version of the Android SDK Tools by following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11514698/249239). It's far from ideal that you have to guess the links rather than reverting from within the SDK Manager directly! Anyway, the closest link that worked was for revision [22.3](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22.3-windows.zip). `jobb` is now working again for me (thankfully).

Comment: Pleased it worked for you. You'd think Google would run such a trivial test before releasing an update!

Answer (score 1):

I tried using jobb from 'android-sdk_r22.6-linux.tgz' and got the same error. Then I downloaded 'adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030.zip', copied 'fat32lib.jar' into the tools/lib directory and jobb runs ok.

They forget to include a jar file in the smaller package.

So download the big package and use that instead.