# screenshot of earlier questions (confuson with existing android application tutorials)

Tags: android, eclipse

I have included the start of the tutorial setup in case that helps with this.

[image: android2][image: Here is a screenshot in the beginning if setting up of a new android project]

Here is a screenshot in the beginning if setting up of a new android project.
It is referencing a "fragment Layout Name" that is not in the tutorials I find. For example, it is not in this tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

This is leading to more and more confusion for me.

(this question is the same question (from me) as [confuson with existing android application tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359107/confuson-with-existing-android-application-tutorials))

Any idea why my set up is different from the official tutorial?

Comment: Maybe you use a different version? It's really a problem? The important thing is to understand the code

Comment: Yes, that is true. My problem is that when I continue through the tutorials it is telling me to modify activity_main.xml, but mine looks nothing like the tutorial, so my ability to understand the code is diminished.

Comment: I think this may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555337/how-to-downgrade-my-sdk-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the version.That is not a problem . There will be a fragment_main.xml will be added to the project. Which can modified or used later. This is for adding the fragments.

I am using the following tools version and i am able to follow the tutorial you have given 
I am listing out the things

eclipse juno - 1.10.2.v2

ADT Tool kit - 22.3.0

SO try with the versions above. I think you are using higher version.

Comment: the version of what? Eclipse? Android? the skd? my phone? What SHOULD the version be in order to follow the tutorials?

Comment: what eclipse are you having

Comment: Indigo Service Release 2

Comment: And also add the screen shot of the previous screen to the screen shot given above . This get you some good answers

Comment: @user3018981 This above difference is mainly due to the adt took kit version. Dont forgot to accept my answer.

Comment: I have uninstalled the ADT and reinstalled it again, but my Android SDK Manager won't permit me to install any version other than the most recent. (22.6). At this point I'm going to uninstall eclipse, and android all together and reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

After the removal of android and eclipse followed by a reinstall of both, the problem has gone away. Just for information, I did not reinstall eclipse. Instead I installed the android SDK bundle that includes eclipse. Thanks everyone for you help.