# Android virtual devices crash immediately on Mac OS X after SDK update

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I just updated my Android SDK packages on my MacBook Pro, and all of my Android virtual devices started crash immediately. The error log is as follows:

```
Process:         emulator [583]
Path:            /Users/dannychia/android-sdk-macosx/tools/emulator
Identifier:      emulator
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  eclipse [500]

Date/Time:       2014-03-19 22:45:21.124 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000003f7d
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x8fe0f318 ImageLoaderMachO::bindLocation(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, ImageLoader const*, unsigned char, char const*, long, char const*) + 278
1   dyld                            0x8fe15ee3 ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::bindAt(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned long, unsigned char, char const*, unsigned char, long, int, char const*, ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::LastLookup*) + 131
2   dyld                            0x8fe203d1 ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::eachBind(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned long (ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::*)(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned long, unsigned char, char const*, unsigned char, long, int, char const*, ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::LastLookup*)) + 577
3   dyld                            0x8fe22c42 ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::doBind(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool) + 290
4   dyld                            0x8fe0cc32 ImageLoader::recursiveBind(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool) + 120
5   dyld                            0x8fe0dea3 ImageLoader::link(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 209
6   dyld                            0x8fe056af dyld::link(ImageLoader*, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 137
7   dyld                            0x8fe0788d dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**) + 3994
8   dyld                            0x8fe018b1 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long) + 779
9   dyld                            0x8fe01057 _dyld_start + 39

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000002  ebx: 0x8fe0f216  ecx: 0xbfffd5dc  edx: 0xa0ccd4c0
  edi: 0x00003f7d  esi: 0x00000002  ebp: 0xbfffd268  esp: 0xbfffd210
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010286  eip: 0x8fe0f318   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0x00003f7d
```

They were working properly before the update. I've been told one common cause of this issue is the use of an external monitor, but I don't have any connected to my MacBook Pro. I deleted my entire SDK folder and installed everything again from scratch, but that didn't help. I also deleted the .android folder to no avail either.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like some bug from Google side, this problem found after "ADT 22.6" update. are you trying the same?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ADT 22.6.

Comment: In Eclipse, open the SDK Manager (via toolbar or Window menu) > Tools > Manager AVDs. This will invoke the external version of the AVD Manager which will properly generate AVDs. Other workaround: use the command-line version (Shell or cmd.exe, cd SDK, "tools\android.bat avd")

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a known [issue 67036](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67036) in SDK 22.6. Two solutions are provided in the comments of this issue:

1. downgrade Android SDK to 22.3
2. use the [Genymotion emulator](http://www.genymotion.com/)

The [downgrade steps from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555337/how-to-downgrade-my-sdk-version) solved the problem for me. If during the boot Android Studio asks to upgrade the SDK, just press Cancel.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add my own (horrendous) experience with this, a colleague pointed out that running Docker at the same time (OSX), causes the emulator to crash - stopping this allows the emulator to start...

Hope this solves the problem for anyone who struggles with the above answers...

Answer (score 0):

Start your AVD manager from your SDK manager and your SDK manager from SDK\tools\Android.bat. I use the ADT 22.6 and i do not see this issue. Does it crash when you try to launch an emulator or just at the boot up of the AVD itself?