# The styles.xml file is not generated in my android project

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-manifest, eclipse-luna

Recently I updated my eclipse Juno to Luna, but now the new project don't generate the android.R file. This probably caused by this AndroidManifest.xml error:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@styles/AppTheme').
```

When I check the values folder, there is no styles.xml. 
This only happens with the new projects, the existing projects (which I created in Juno) work fine.
I've tried updating everything in SDK manager, but I still get the error.

Comment: You can create style.xml manually.

Comment: I tried, but it still gives an error

Comment: show your style.xml and Manifest.xml files.

Comment: you haven't defined what your theme is, although something is pointing to a theme '@styles/AppTheme' which you usually define yourself (not generated)

Comment: When I was using Juno, I never defined the theme, the default value was @styles/AppTheme, but there were never any issues

Comment: @Bouss i use Juno and Luna and never had this problem.

Comment: @Suvitruf Yeah I have this issue too, but only when, in the project creator, I select 'Holo light with actionbar'. However, I mostly go with no theme (default) and it works just fine.

Comment: Are you running the latest adt and Android Support Library?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics, but I just fixed this on both my Linux machine and Windows machine. It stops producing the style.xml after you upgrade your Android SDK Tools to revision 24 or higher.

I fixed mine by downgrading as seen at [this other SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555337/how-to-downgrade-my-sdk-version) using the version 23.0.5 (I'd post direct links, but I don't have enough points here to post more than two).

Again, I have no idea WHY this is happening, only that it prevents me from creating new projects with the latest SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when I updated my Android SDK Tools. When I build a new Android project, it doesn't generate the styles.xml in res/values/. But after I builded a new styles.xml and copied content from other project, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The error has been corrected in Android SDK Tools 24.0.2. I just test it now.

Answer (score 0):

If it happened during your first Andriod App build, it must be just like my case.

It happened to me when Eclipse(Luna)/AndroidSDK(not Android Stduio) were used with the latest tools and library as of Jan. 14, 2015 during the project like HelloWorld. When I installed those tools and made HelloWorld the first app, I accepted all the defaults. - **This is the problem in my case.**

First, check whether or not the "Android Support Library" library is installed. 
If not, install it. It is not installed by default. 
You may do it all in "Android SDK manager" available in the menu.

(Android SDK Manager -> Extra -> Android Support Library)

Blessings,
(a debtor)<><