# No resource found that matches the given name (@style/AppTheme)

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-manifest

Everytime I create a new Android Application Project in Eclipse I get the following error:

Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').

The error leads to the following line in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

I am not sure what the problem could be

Comment: Check out your value/style folder. there will be a theme. which is that theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Originally when creating the project, I chose Android 4.1 Jellybean as the target SDK, but instead chose Android 4.X (L Preview) and this error went away.

Comment: Try downgrading adt.. as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555337/how-to-downgrade-my-sdk-version