# Cordova build fails, can't find ${appt}

Tags: android, cordova, ant

The command  `cordova build android` fails with the following output

```
BUILD FAILED
F:\Programs\SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:597: The following error occurred while executing this line:
F:\Programs\SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
F:\Programs\SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:694: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
"F:\code\asistenciaBT\platforms\android\CordovaLib\${aapt}" 
(in directory   "F:\code\asistenciaBT\platforms\android\CordovaLib"): CreateProcess error=2, 
El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
```

Meaning, as far as I can tell, that ant can't find the aapt file. Ant is installed:

```
ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
```

`ANDROID_HOME` and `PATH` are correctly set as well. I have made cordova work on this system before, now it just refuses to.

Should cordova be looking for appt in the project directory? Shouldn't it be looking on `ANDROID_HOME/build_tools` ?

Some further detail, in case is needed:

```
npm -v
2.7.4

node -v
v0.12.2

cordova -v
5.1.1

os: windows 8.1 pro 64 bits
```

Project was cloned from github so it *might* have some inherited incompatibility somewhere.

EDIT:

Just tested 'cordova build' on a new project and it fails with the same error.

Comment: I'm having similar issues

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like ant commands are broken in Android SDK 24.3, which `cordova build` is using. I downgraded to previous release (24.2.0) and ant works fine now.

You can download previous SDK from:
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r24.2-windows.zip

EDIT: There is better solution, See kartikeya's answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31603358/1453578

Also, if you're not using cordova but relying on ant to build your android project, just move to gradle already.

Comment: Fyi: for the osx or linux versions of the tools zip, just replace "windows" with "macosx" or "linux". Howto downgrade: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555337/how-to-downgrade-my-sdk-version

Comment: Downgrading??? Downgrading anything is a best option for rusty developers. Instead of this, I highly recommend Kartikeya's solution.

Answer (score 3):

no need to downgrade or upgrade your SDK. Follow this step.
Go to .../sdk/tools/ant/build.xml and find there:

```
    <!-- find location of build tools -->
    <getbuildtools name="android.build.tools.dir" verbose="${verbose}" />
```

add below the lines:

```
    <property name="aidl" location="${android.build.tools.dir}/aidl${exe}" />
    <property name="aapt" location="${android.build.tools.dir}/aapt${exe}" />
    <property name="dx" location="${android.build.tools.dir}/dx${bat}" />
    <property name="zipalign" location="${android.build.tools.dir}/zipalign${exe}" />
```

Comment: Highly recommend this solution. Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

SDK is broken ... downgrade to previous version !
i.e , ant version 1.9.4 TO Ant 1.9.5 or downgrade android skd tools

Answer (score 2):

ant build looks definitely broken. Even using an older SDK was still failing for me. I had Cordova 4.2. My solution was to switch to gradle build which is now the default in cordova 5. (so I guess you updated to Cordova 5 but did not update the android project)

```
$ npm install -g cordova
```

Project needs to be updated to use the gradle build

```
$ cordova platform update android
```

Building should now be using gradle

```
$ cordova build android
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading Android SDK Tools to 24.3.3 solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting back to **24.3.1** solves it.
osx:  http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.3.1-macosx.zip

more on this issue here:   https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176488

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following command:

```
 cordova platform update android@5.0.0
```