# How to downgrade project sdk from 23 to 21 in android studio 1.4.1 without getting error?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started install android studio this year and i get a default sdk of 23 everytime i open my project. However, i would like to downgrade it to sdk 21. But i have been getting error from other java file. How should i solve this matter? I have been following from this tutorial "[Changing API level Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio)". However after gradle sync, the error come out

[image]

Comment: Do click at the image i upload to look at the error from java file.

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555337/how-to-downgrade-my-sdk-version

Comment: go to build.gradle file of your project change compileSdkVersion 21

Comment: Going down is a bad idea.