# How to install older Android SDK Platform-tools 23.0.1 in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have made a mistake of upgrading my Platform-tools from Android SDK Manager.
As a consequence I cannot launch my project.
There is something wrong with launching the project. I get the error:

```
[2016-07-26 18:20:57 - MyAppliaction] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2016-07-26 18:20:57 - MyAppliaction] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2016-07-26 18:20:57 - MyAppliaction] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

If i try to execute adb via command line I get:

> The procedure entry point WSAPoll could not be located in the dynamic
>   link library WS2_32.dll.

```
Eclipse version: Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Windows XP
Android SDK tools: 25.1.7
Android Platform-tools: 24.0.1
```

I would like to revert to the last vesrion I know which worked, but this is not available any more in Android SDK Manager.

I have tried substituting some old adb in folder platform-tools, but that does not work either. How to return to older working version of Platform-tools?

Comment: 1) Upgrading the SDK is good as you get the latest build tool optimizations and methods and libraries 2) You may want to download Eclipse Neon (or Andmore), which is now officially supports Android development again

Comment: Though, I think the problem is that you are running XP and from what I just found `WSAPoll` doesn't exist

Comment: No. WinXp are not the problem. Version 23.0.1 did work OK.

Comment: You can simply open the SDK manager and uninstall the version you downloaded, can't you?

Comment: No. There is no version I downloaded. The SDK manager just offers the new version which does not work. I need the older version 23.0.1.

Comment: Yes, it does offer older versions. http://i.stack.imgur.com/x024b.png

Comment: Android SDK Build-tools is not the same as Android SDK Platform-tools. Two different things. And in your picture only Platform-tools 24.0.1 are listed.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that `adb` is tied to a particular version of the platform tools. You can download the adb binary separately, for example.

Comment: I took some older version of ADB. Ye it did produce some version error. It is not as simple as copy paste a few files.

Comment: I've had good experiences with this, though that won't necessarily fix Eclipse in any way - http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790

Comment: Well I actually managed to start some older ADB. But eclipse would not use it. Some error, cam't remember which. And I really need capability to launch project form Eclipse. I really cannt believe there is no option to downgrade. Ind I have swore to my self in the past never ever to update tools. My fault for thinking that google might have doscovered testing.

Comment: XP is no longer officially supported by Microsoft, so I personally doubt Google would really regression test that. If you feel adventurous, Ubuntu or Linux Mint are good OS's to develop on.

Comment: The question is basicaly how to revert to older version of Android SDK Platform tools, not which operating systems exist out there. That is completely different topic.

Comment: For reference, I got that from here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23022718/2308683

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to download version `23.0.1` for windows from this link

http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-windows.zip

Then, you may navigate to the Android SDK download location, backup the existing `platform-tools` folder for safe-keeping just in-case, and extract that zip there.

Comment: Thank you. When I tried with older version of ADB I did not have a complete folder. Comparing to yours it did miss some files. What I did is replace platform-tools folder as I did before, restarted Eclipse and it launched the app on device. If you could be so  kind please tell, how did you get this link. Is there a repository to browse. How to fund such things, because I searched for this a4rchice, yet to no avail. And while you are at it emphasize that Eclipse must be restarted, In short... upvoted. My vote will be shown after I get 15 points. Sorry about that.