# Cordova: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android, cordova

I am having problem to build android with Cordova, when I execute `cordova build android`, I receive this error:

```
Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

I have do this to fix it:

```
sudo nano  ~/.bash_profile
```

and add this line:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/tools
```

then this:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

but I get again that error when I build, how can I fix it?

UPDATE:

This is the line I Added in the bash:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/tools
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk
```

Comment: You updated `PATH`, but where is `ANDROID_HOME`?

Comment: I update my question

Comment: maybe try logging out and logging in.

Comment: I tried the restart, the login logout, nothing

Comment: You need to run the `android` command and setup the SDK first.

Comment: does `echo $ANDROID_HOME` work? have you setup Android Studio or just SDK?

Comment: @suraj the result of `echo $ANDROID_HOME` is this: `/Users/piero/Library/Android/sdk` so I think it's right

Comment: @cricket_007 I have installed sdk with android studio, I have also tried to create a sample project and run it on simulator and all works. Anyway I have tried this: `android` and this is the result: `The android command is no longer available.
For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager`

Comment: Oh, guess I haven't updated mine recently... That command works on my Mac

Comment: does `sudo cordova build android` work?

Comment: @suraj nope, same error

Comment: Here is solution this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555337/how-to-downgrade-my-sdk-version

Answer (score 47):

The recent [Android SDK tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html) removed the `android` command.

```
$ android -v
The android command is no longer available.
For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
```

`cordova` is behind the change and someone seems to be working on it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12554

You can also downgrade your tools to a version where the `android` was still available.

Nevertheless, I found a way to run the Android app without having to downgrade my SDK tools. I would (1) run `cordova prepare`, then (2) run the command I need from Android Studio. In my case, running it on the emulator was enough.

UPDATE: The issue [CB-12554](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12554) is resolved now and was released with the `cordova-android@6.2.0` release.

UPDATE: There were several related subsequent patches done and the newest version is `cordova-android@6.2.3`. Run `cordova platform rm android; cordova platform add android@6.2.3` to fix the issues.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I feel like an idiot but I cannot find where previous SDK versions are kept. Will keep searching of course and report back here if I find anything. Also, will the older SDKs work with the latest release of Android Studio? I have been using Android Studio to prepare our Cordova releases for the app store.

Comment: To save others time, I have done a lot of searching and it doesn't appear that previous versions of Android Studio are made available any more. This stable channel (http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable) is now obsolete. Taking partial paths from the download links listed on the official download page results in 404s (https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads). I cannot find previous versions of tools hosted anywhere. We might be stuck in a holding pattern for now.

Comment: @Rjak I updated my answer but you could probably run `cordova prepare` which would set up all the required files inside `/platforms/android` then run an Android command as if it was a pure Android app. It worked for me.

Comment: I am still getting this error.  I am on Cordova 6.5.0.  I don't think the issue is resolved.

Comment: @clavio the version number 6.2 refers to the version of cordova-android platform (you can check your current version by running: cordova platform ls). 6.2.1 was released recently. Check out [Cordova Android 6.2.1 Released!](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/04/05/android-release.html) for more info and how to update

Comment: Still not working for me at this date with latest Android SDK and Cordova Android 6.2.1.

Comment: @Grsmto I had no problem with the latest release.

Comment: FYI Newest version is 6.2.3 which fixes some other related bugs

Comment: I thought about something like that. Great advice!

Comment: `cordova platform update android@6.2.2` will solve the issue. I guess cordova team has fixed this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668185/could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-your-andr

Answer (score 31):

For me this work , first check your cordova android version

```
cordova platform version android
```

it shows 5.0 to me and after that upgrade the version by this command

```
cordova platform update android
```

Comment: important to note: you should also have the corresponding android sdk for that version

Comment: I had to cordova platform rm android &
cordova platform add android

Answer (score 22):

TL;DR
In some cases, **even if you have successfully added android sdk to your path** the problem still persists, the reason is related to your Android `tools/` folder version, currently the `android` command is not supported anymore **but it is still required** by the command `ionic cordova build android`, then you should download an old one.

Now that you know where the problem is, let's get into the solution:

1. Download an old sdk tools version according to your platform [Mac](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip), [Windows](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip), [Linux](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip).
2. Replace the current `tools/` folder in `/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk` on **Mac** or `C:\Users\[account]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk` on **Windows** or `~/Android/Sdk` on **Linux** by the downloaded `tools/` folder.
3. Restart your command-line and be happy!

Comment: Why in the world, is this nowhere to be found in the documentation?!  This should be plastered all over the cordova documentation.  Thank you so much.

Comment: You are gem man ! after hours of madness, I finally landed here.

Answer (score 3):

@Rjak here is the [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555337/how-to-downgrade-my-sdk-version) for downgrading SDK version with valid links for older SDK versions. It works for me with same issue, after downgraded to tools v25.2.5 & platform-tools to v25.0.3 build successful

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to get this to work. I am looking at v25.2.5. I found a tools package at http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-macosx.zip, but there is no corresponding platform tools package at http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r25.2.5-macosx.zip.

Comment: Would be helpful if Google gave directory listings instead of 404s!! :)

Comment: here is the list of available [platform-tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html).
So you've got 404 just because they really don't have it :)
try this [one](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r25.0.3-macosx.zip) instead.

Answer (score 2):

As someone else stated, it is because of the android command being deprecated:

```
   C:\>android
   **************************************************************************
   The "android" command is deprecated.
   For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
   For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
   and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
   **************************************************************************
```

In my case, I managed to fix it changing the newer android.bat that is bundled in the sdk, in the "tools" folder.

Just change this lines in the `sdk/tools/android.bat`:

**From this**: (Line ~20)

`set avd_objects=;avd;target;device;`

**To**:

`set avd_objects=;avd;targets;device;`

**From This**: (Line ~37)

```
echo android list target
```

**To**:

```
echo android list targets
```

Explanation: The cordova build.bat will eventually call check_reqs.js script, and thats where this validation is done. If you look for the actual error text, it shows that the script is trying to call "android list target**s** --compact" command, which I assume was the older way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Update to new Android package to solve the error -

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
cordova build android --release
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question uninstalling Android Studio and install the CLI SDK Manager following this guide:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Installing-Android-SDK-Tools

Comment: But this is not optimal solution

Answer (score 0):

In My Case, This is a Scenario

1.I have an **SDK platforms tools Version 23**

2.I have added the Android Platform to My Cordova Project

3.It works fines Until I update the **SDK to 26**

4.After Updating the SDK it Throws the same Error

> Cordova: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it
>   is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment
>   variable

5. I just Resolved this by removing and Adding the Android platforms in my Project

   **cordova platform remove android**

   **cordova platform add android**
6. Now it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

In My case I resolved this issue by giving proper permission to android executable file.

I was running android build from Jenkins. So when I downloaded android SDK, in /usr/local/android-sdk/tools/ I saw android executable file. the permission of this file is root because in Jenkins server(ubuntu server) I installed android-sdk as a root user.

When I was running the job I was getting an error as
"Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."

But ANDROID_HOME is having correct path set as well as Android-SDK is also present. Then I check the permission so below are the things I have done and given permission to the whole tools folder.

1. `cd /usr/local/android-sdk/tools`
2. `ls -lt` (when you run this command you will see android permission as root:root)
3. `chown jenkins:jenkins android`
4. or else you can give jenkins:jenkins permission to all the files present in the tools folder by coming at location "`/usr/local/android-sdk`" and then run the command "`chown jenkins:jenkins -R tools/`".
5. I am running as a jenkins user but if you are running the build as some other user then use that username.