# Android SDK not found.

Tags: android, cordova, sdk

Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

This is the problem [image: Problem]

Cordova cant acces to the SDK even it is installed , i dont know how to change the default location but i have tried to create the android_home variable but it didnt work .

Comment: Also i want to install gradle but i dont know how either

Comment: Alex: does calling `android` open the android sdk manager or give you an error message?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is connected with actualization of Android. Android depreciated his tool: `android`, you can check it typing `android` in command line. You should see:

```
*************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

You can solve it updating cordova

```
npm install -g cordova
```

and android platform in cordova

```
cordova platform rm android; cordova platform add android@6.2.3
```

Source

> [Cordova: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645285/cordova-android-sdk-not-found-make-sure-that-it-is-installed-if-it-is-not-at)