# how to setup environmental variable for android in mac

Tags: android, macos, angular, android-studio, ionic2

My **.bash_profile** looks like this

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/subbarao/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/subbarao/Library/Android/sdk/
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
even $(user/libexec/path_helper -s)
```

When I give `ionic platform add android` I am getting like this [image: img]

When I give `ionic run android` I am running into this error

> Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
>   Looked here: /Users/subbarao/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `cordova-android v 6.1.2`. There was an issue with cordova-android. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42805031/4826457).

Try

```
ionic platform add android@6.2.1
```

Or

```
ionic platform add android@latest
```

**Update**:

if you are using ionic cli v3, the command is

```
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```

Comment: for ios settup i am facing this issue any ideahttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680366/how-to-build-and-deploy-an-ios-api-file-in-real-device-using-mac @suraj

Answer (score 1):

Update SDK and gradle version and then try following commands in the terminal

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/ADT/sdk
```

PATH environment variable

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
```

Comment: can you provide me the full /.bash_profile code i mean path

Comment: /Users/{YOUR_USER_NAME}/Library/Android/sdk