# How to build and deploy an ios api file in real device using MAC

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, angular, ionic2

i am new to mac, so for i have installed xcode and successfully added the platform for ios.

When i give `adb devices` i am not able to detect my device name for iphone but when i connect android and give `adb devices` i am getting my device .

when i give `ionic build ios` i'm getting the following errors. i don't know how to enable the developer option in iphone

> === BUILD TARGET myFirst OF PROJECT myFirst WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
>
> Check dependencies
>
> Signing for "myFirst" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
>   Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'
>
> ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>       Check dependencies
>   (1 failure)
>
> Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/subbarao/Desktop/myFirst/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,myFirst.xcworkspace,-scheme,myFirst,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,myFirst.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/subbarao/Desktop/myFirst/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/subbarao/Desktop/myFirst/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524148/requires-a-development-team-select-a-development-team-in-the-project-editor-cod)

Comment: @l'L'l i tried that one but not able to get the solution

Comment: Tried which one? You need to setup the Development Team so you can codesign it.

Comment: i am not getting any error in my xcode the above error is from my terminal and i have success fully setup the development team and codesign i have changed everything to the ios developer mode which are all in the dont code sign @l'L'l

Comment: `ionic run android` is working fine and `ionic run ios --device` is not working also `ionic build ios` is working fine @l'L'l

Answer (score 0):

You need a development provisioning profile on your build machine. Apps can run on the simulator without a profile, but they are required to run on an actual device.

If you open the project in Xcode, it may automatically set up provisioning for you. Otherwise you will have to create go to the iOS Dev Center and create a profile.

[cordova run with ios error .. Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166175/cordova-run-with-ios-error-error-code-65-for-command-xcodebuild-with-args/39875191)

Same question here by this guy
Try to sign in as ios dev account in Xcode

or try

ionic platform remove ios

ionic platform add ios

i was getting the same error but i tried the above command and its working now
thanks

Comment: how to enable developer option in ios @HaSnen Tai

Comment: As i am not a IOS user so i dont really know that but please go through this like this might be helpful https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/159197.I debug apps on Emulator and If you will try this command                        ionic platform remove ios

ionic platform add ios then it will work try that Thanks @MohanGopi