# Android command is depreciated after updating SDK

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm building an ionic app using webstorm. I recently opened android studio and updated the sdk and now I'm not able to build my project in webstorm.

I get the following when choosing a target device
[image: I get the following when choosing a target device]

I've tried renaming the `home/android/sdk/tools` to tools2, didn't work.
Also, using the sdk manager I'm able to roll back SDK build tools to the previous version (didn't fix it) but not the SDK tools. So then, I tried using [sdkmanager command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html) and I can see . . .

```
  tools  | 26.0.2  | Android SDK Tools | tools/
```

However there are no available packages (say I want one version older v25) to install - only build tools again or platforms, system images etc. No previous versions available on developer.android.com either

PS. Using SDK platform 6.0, SDK tools v26.0.2

Comment: what is the cordova android version?

Comment: Not sure what that is, cordova is version 6.5.0 and ionic is version 2.2.1

Comment: since it is an ionic app. it uses cordova android platform.. you will have a platforms folder in the project ..check platforms.json in it

Comment: Ah okay it's 6.1.2. Thanks

Comment: Ah.. same answer as this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43677221/4826457

Comment: I removed android and then added again using @lastest but its still having the same issue. Thanks

Comment: I've downgraded my SDK by switching the folders with the ones I downloaded from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_rXXX-linux.zip.
It's no longer showing the error message about android being depreciated, but now its simply an empty list - it's not showing my AVDs.