# Android target : not installed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am unable to run `ionic run android`. After I checked with `cordova requirements`, it shows

```
Android target: Not installed
Android SDK not found.
```

[image]

**How should I solve the problem**? I have my SDK in D drive where I have set ANDROID_HOME and path correctly, I suppose
[image][image]

Also, I do android list target, it shown as below. How should I intsall it if it is needed to fix teh error?[image]

Attached the cordova android version

[image]

Comment: what is your cordova-android version?

Comment: @suraj, please refer to the edited update

Comment: its very old https://stackoverflow.com/a/43677221/4826457 also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42805031/4826457

Comment: @suraj, i am using windows 10, is it the same? May I know what is actually the cause of the error? My android version 5.1.1 is higher than my SDK?

Comment: windows or osx doesnt matter.. check the second link.. `android` command is deprecated and older cordova-android still uses that command which gives the error

Comment: @suraj is the solution is to run `cordova platform rm android; cordova platform add android@6.2.3`? The project in the directory is using android 5.1.1. My SDk is SDK android 4.1 which I intended to use. Is possible the project will be in android 4.1?

Comment: you will have to install older android command line tools..not sure where you would get that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148320/discussion-between-behappy-and-suraj).

Answer (score 6):

You can follow this link [set ANDROID_HOME](http://www.360logica.com/blog/how-to-set-path-environmental-variable-for-sdk-in-windows/)  which I got help from or follow below guide.

I had similar trouble but managed to fix it. After successful installation of android studio, Android SDK will be downloaded by default to a directory like this *"C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1"* where "abc" in this case is your PC name. AppData is a hidden folder.

Next step is to set ANDROID SDK path. From Advanced System Settings, click Environment Variables then under User variables add New as shown below.

[image]

Next, add android 'tools' and  'platform-tools' to System variables' 'Path' as shown below. These tools are inside sdk folder.

[image]

Set up is done. Open cmd and issue android command. If all is well, you should see below output.
[image]

Finally open a new terminal window and navigate to your cordova project directory, in my case "hello" and check platfrom requirements. All should be fine now.
[image]

Comment: thanks! I'm on Mac, but your advice to add the tools to PATH solved the problem. I forgot that I modified my PATH in one terminal window, but forgot to source it in the window running the `cordova requirements` command

Comment: this did not fix my issue, but I rated for the quality of documentation

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The issue was I was using the latest version of Java which was 1**0.0.1**

You can check yourself by typing in terminal:

```
java --version
```

And it was

```
java 10.0.1 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

Currently, Cordova needs on their documentation page as JDK 8. [SEE DOC HERE](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#java-development-kit-jdk)

You can download JDK 8 from the official website [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Once you download you need to set up JAVA_HOME variable. [Use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/setting-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-osx-10-9?answertab=active#tab-top) for setting up JAVA HOME when you have multiple version of JAVA installed.

Then you can run

```
cordova requirements
```

or

```
cordova build android
```

This worked for me. Hope it helps someone.