# Cordova "Create your first Cordova app" can't get pass "Android target: not installed"

Tags: android, windows, cordova, target

I am trying to get Cordova to work, for the first time.

I already added the paths checked the android manifest and project.properties

I have android sdk platform 14, 16 and 20 to 27 installed.

I don't know what else to do...

And i always get:

```
C:\Android\Cordova\hello>cordova requirements
Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annota
tion/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(Sc
hemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHa
ndler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema

        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinCla
ssLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(C
lassLoaders.java:185)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        ... 5 more
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.1\bin\
gradle
(node:6696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Some of requirements
 check failed
    at C:\Users\julio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js:414:27

    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\julio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_
modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\julio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\julio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\julio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cord
ova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
    at flush (C:\Users\julio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modul
es\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:6696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection
 id: 1)
(node:6696) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

C:\Android\Cordova\hello>
```

image off path definition:

[path cordova android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXkOq.png)

Values

```
%PATH%
C:\Users\julio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;
C:\Users\julio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Users\julio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\;

%android_home%
C:\Users\julio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\
```

*** Solved it. I had java jdk-9.0.4 installed, installed jdk1.8.0_162 and redirected java_home there and now everything is working so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android target : not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903644/android-target-not-installed)

Comment: I tried that before i post, it didn't work.

Comment: Take a look at this also:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667277/cordova-phonegap-android-target-not-installed-android-studio-installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667277/cordova-phonegap-android-target-not-installed-android-studio-installed)

Comment: *** I solved it. I had java jdk-9.0.4 installed, installed jdk1.8.0_162 and redirected java_home there and now everything is working so far.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
I had java JDK 9.0.4 installed.
Installed JDK 8u162 and redirected java_home there and now everything is working.