# ubuntu: can't run ionic app on emulator because android SDK doesn't exist

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using ionic2 and when I run app as `ionic cordova run android`. I got this

> error: ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Android SDK not
>   found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default
>   location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable. You may not have
>   the required environment or OS to run this project

although I have android studio and SDK installed and set it in bashrc file as:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/shimaa/Android/Sdk"
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/shimaa/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/shimaa/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin
```

but when I write android or sdkmanager in terminal I got this error:

> No command 'android' found and sdkmanager: command not found

which means that android is not installed although it is installed and I run it.
anyone can tell me the solution ?

Comment: what is the output for `cordova requirements` command in your project folder. Also which version of cordova-android platform are you using?

Comment: @suraj this is the output: Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed .
Android SDK: installed 
Android target: not installed 
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
Gradle: not installed 
Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /home/shimaa/Android/Sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple OS X: not installed

Comment: what is the `cordova-android` version? it is shown in platforms.json in platforms folder

Comment: @suraj: Installed platforms: android 5.1.1, ios 4.0.1
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, ubuntu, webos

Comment: platforms.json in platforms folder

Comment: @suraj "ios": "4.0.1",
    "android": "5.1.1"

Comment: ok.. check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676836/how-to-setup-environmental-variable-for-android-in-mac/43677221#43677221). I believe it is the same problem

Comment: @suraj: sorry but I always have this error when I run ionic cordova platform add android@latest --save the error is [ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

Comment: what error do you get when you run `cordova platform add android@latest`?

Comment: @suraj ✖ Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.
        
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova platform add android@latest
        --save (exit code 1):
        
        Error: Platform android already added.
and it not solve the problem