# ionic2: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using ionic2. When I run

```
command ionic cordova run android
```

,I get this error:

> ✖ Running command - failed!
>   [ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
>   You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):
>   Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting
>   setting it manually.
>   Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH'
>   to include path to valid SDK directory.

Although I had set android environment variable in ~/.bachrc.
When I run command:

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME in terminal
```

,I have output:

> /home/shimaa/Android/Sdk

That is what I wrote in ~/.bashrc:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/shimaa/Android/Sdk"
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/shimaa/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk/tools
```

can anyone tell me what is the problem and thank you in advance

Comment: Didnt you ask this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45386890/ubuntu-cant-run-ionic-app-on-emulator-because-android-sdk-doesnt-exist ?

Answer (score 0):

For me I have Android_Home path inside my "Path" as "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\26.0.0" After setting up the path, restart your system.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu and I don't Know how to set Android home path inside your PAth, is there any link that describe it?

Comment: You can refer to this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256279/how-to-set-android-home-path-in-ubuntu-please-provide-the-steps). i am working with windows system. I hope it helps you.