# how to resolve this ERROR running one or more of the platform when i am runnning "ionic run android --device"

Tags: angularjs, git, ionic-framework, git-bash

```
$ ionic run android --device
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\user\Desktop\transroads\jvdappNew\jvdApp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:/Users/user/Desktop/transroads/jvdappNew/jvdApp
add to body class: platform-android
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project.
```

It was working properly but when i updated my Android Studio there is installed another SDK also now i am having two SDK in the ANDROID_HOME path those are SDK and SDK1. SDK is having API23 and SDK1 API24.
whenever i am running command "ionic run android --device" terminal always shows that error i have discuss above.

Before update of Android Studio everything was working properly but after the update i am unable to run ionic application on my mobile device.ANDROID_HOME path is C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk; and i am having SDK1 folder also after the Android Studios updation on that location.

AVD Manager.exe and SDK Manager.exe those files are only in SDK and SDK1 having nothing like that.**Please help me out of this**.

Anyone please tell me both the platform can run over a SDK Manager?

Comment: what does `cordova requirements` command give?

Comment: $ cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed .
Android SDK: installed
Android target: not installed
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
Gradle: not installed
Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper
Error: Some of requirements check failed

Comment: hmm.. which is your cordova android platform version?

Comment: Cordova version is 6.0.0

Comment: ok..adding an aswer

Comment: cordova android platform version?

Comment: cordova android platform version is 6.0.0 and  i have tried your solution but it is not working it says platform already added.

Comment: remove the platform and add the new one

Comment: i have followed your instruction when i am running command ionic plateform add android@6.2.3 then there is a new error that is Error: cordovaProject.projectConfig.getFileResources is not a function

Comment: update cordova cli

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your cordova android platform. Basically the older version till 6.2.0 used `android` command which is deprecated in the SDK.This was patched in 6.2.0

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42805031/4826457) for more info.

Update your cordova cli first:

```
npm install -g cordova@latest
```

You can update to the latest platform by doing:

```
ionic platform add android@6.2.3
```

Or

```
ionic platform add android@latest
```

For **IONIC CLI v3** the command is:

```
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```