# Android SDK not found error when creating android APK file

Tags: angular, ionic2

```
$ ionic build android --release  > ionic-hello-world@0.0.0 ionic:build D:\Mobile\Backup\Music App\music > ionic-app-scripts build "--release"  [16:42:24]  ionic-app-scripts 1.3.7 
[16:42:24]  build dev started ... 
[16:42:24]  clean started ... 
[16:42:24]  clean finished in less than 1 ms 
[16:42:24]  copy started ... 
[16:42:24]  transpile started ... 
[16:42:27]  transpile finished in 2.48 s 
[16:42:27]  preprocess started ... 
[16:42:27]  deeplinks started ... 
[16:42:27]  deeplinks finished in 16 ms 
[16:42:27]  preprocess finished in 16 ms 
[16:42:27]  webpack started ... 
[16:42:27]  copy finished in 3.07 s 
[16:42:34]  webpack finished in 7.47 s
[16:42:34]  sass started ... 
[16:42:37]  sass finished in 2.38 s 
[16:42:37]  postprocess started ... 
[16:42:37]  postprocess finished in 15 ms 
[16:42:37]  lint started ... 
[16:42:37]  build dev finished in 12.45 s 
[16:42:38]  lint finished in 1.82 s
```

ERROR building one of the platforms: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable. You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project  Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Comment: ANDROID_HOME="C:\Users\OSITH\AppData\Local\Android\sdk;"

Comment: added android platform 5.1.1 perfectly without ant error but can't build APK file.

Comment: There is actually an [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44068746/edit) link on your question. Which is preferred to adding more information as comments.

Comment: Sorry, you mean. @Neil Lunn

Comment: what is the output for `cordova requirements`?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/44022624/4826457

Comment: $ cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed .
Android SDK: installed
Android target: not installed
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the defau               lt location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
Gradle: not installed
Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Andr               oid SDK.
Looked here: C:\Users\OSITH\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wra               pper
Error: Some of requirements check failed @suraj

Comment: @suraj show the result when type cordova requirements

Comment: @suraj Thanks a lot it works for me