# Android SDK not found, even though ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set, also getting perfect result on typing 'android' in cmd

Tags: android, cordova

**OS : Windows 7**
I am getting "Android SDK not found" error in cordova,
I have added environment variable "ANDROID_HOME" in user variable section

```
C:\Users\KDN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

and also added "tools" and "platform-tools" in PATH in System variable section

```
C:\Users\KDN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools
C:\Users\KDN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

after setting this variables, when I type android in command prompt

```
C:\Users\KDN>android
```

I get following result

```
**************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
**************************************************************************

Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

but still when I try to execute

```
cordova build android
```

I get following error

```
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

I am using android version 5.1.1 in cordova and same is installed in SDK too.

Comment: I have just successfully build the project with android version 6.0, but again I tried it with android version 5.1.1 and 5.0 it gives me same error, so I think problem reside in cordova android version 5.1.1 and 5.0

Answer (score 0):

check this link [Cordova: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645285/cordova-android-sdk-not-found-make-sure-that-it-is-installed-if-it-is-not-at)

If not working try to reinstall again.. sometime it doesn't take the values