# NoClassDefFoundError android/support/v4/animation/AnimatorCompatHelper

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin

After updating Android Studio to 2.3.1 and gradle to 3.3 i noticed that the app is crashing on a certain activity. Before the update, everything was fine. I've wasted a day on this thing and I really can't seem to figure out why I'm getting
a **'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/animation/AnimatorCompatHelper;'** fatal exception.

I'll upload also the most important parts of the build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion ANDROID_TARGET_SDK
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
       ....
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
       ...
    }
    debug {
        ..
    }
}

sourceSets.main {
   ..
}

flavorDimensions "abi", "countMode"
productFlavors {
    ...
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
}

 repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

dependencies {
   if (ENABLE_ABI_ARM7) armv7Compile project(path: ':countlib', configuration: 'armv7Release')
if (!USE_CUSTOM_OPENCV) {
    if (ENABLE_ABI_X86) x86Compile project(path: ':countlib', configuration: 'x86Release')
    if (ENABLE_ABI_ARM) armCompile project(path: ':countlib', configuration: 'armRelease')
    if (ENABLE_ABI_MIPS) mipsCompile project(path: ':countlib', configuration: 'mipsRelease')
}
compile project(':photoviewlib')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:10.2.1'

// Include the sdk as a dependency
compile ('com.onedrive.sdk:onedrive-sdk-android:1.2+') {
    transitive = false
}

// Include the gson dependency
compile ('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1')

// Include supported authentication methods for your application
compile ('com.microsoft.services.msa:msa-auth:0.8.+')
compile ('com.microsoft.aad:adal:1.1.+')

// HTTP client
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'

compile "com.github.danielnilsson9:color-picker-view:1.4.0@aar"
compile 'com.github.crosswall:Android-Coverflow:release-v1.0.4'
compile 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:2.1.2'
}
```

Here is the full exception stack:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/animation/AnimatorCompatHelper;
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator.resetAnimation(DefaultItemAnimator.java:513)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator.animateRemove(DefaultItemAnimator.java:187)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.SimpleItemAnimator.animateDisappearance(SimpleItemAnimator.java:86)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.animateDisappearance(RecyclerView.java:3046)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$700(RecyclerView.java:144)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$4.processDisappeared(RecyclerView.java:416)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ViewInfoStore.process(ViewInfoStore.java:201)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2931)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1133)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1192)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3178)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17945)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2716)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2417)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1487)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7450)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographe
```

Comment: remove animation from recycle view

Comment: Try to downgrade you Android SDK to version 23.
Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11514698/3283247

Comment: @ Alexey Did it. Still not working, same exception.
@JaydeepPatel Can't seem to find any Animation Item in code or xml.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Solved by following the answer from this question: [Android Support Repo 46.0.0 with Android Studio 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42949974/android-support-repo-46-0-0-with-android-studio-2-3)

**Solution:**

Added this script in **build.gradle** file at the end of app.module

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '24.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help other people.

Comment: Can you offer any explanation as to why that solution works for *this crash*?

Comment: Spent about 4 hours on this before finding your answer, thanks! My problem was due to com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0 pulling in a much more recent version of the android support libraries than the app had been built on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will resolved the error

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```