# NoClassDefFoundError while clicking 'Effect' on AdobeCreativeSDK

Tags: android, adobecreativesdk

I am using creativeSDK and while clicking on the effect button it shows this type of error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.applone.test, PID: 21392
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
Landroid/support/v4/animation/AnimatorCompatHelper;
```

**i just solved by using preferable dependency.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError android/support/v4/animation/AnimatorCompatHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320496/noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v4-animation-animatorcompathelper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just have to change version of the dependency in gradle