# flutter SDK version solving failed

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

```
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.2.

Because instagram_clone_flutter depends on persian_date >=0.0.2 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
```

I tried and changed:
pubspec.yaml ->  environment:
sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
after :flutter get
pub get
pub upgrade
flutter update-packages
I still facing the same error .restarting didnt work.
flutter clean didnt help.
if i downgrade to sdk version 2 or download it, it will again upgrade to version 3.2.0
flutter doctor returns no errors.
i need my packages to be in my app and i dont want to delete them.
last time that it worked, sdk version was 2.7

```
dependencies:

  flutter_chat_ui: ^1.6.4
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.4
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  file_picker: ^4.6.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.3
  firebase_core: ^1.10.5
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.3
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_chat_types: ^3.4.5
  flutter_linear_datepicker: ^2.0.4
  flutter_map: ^2.2.0
  flutter_osm_plugin: ^0.37.2+2
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.1
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
  intl: ^0.18.0
  mime: ^1.0.2
  open_file: ^3.2.1
  open_street_map_search_and_pick: ^0.0.9
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  persian_date: ^0.1.5
  provider: ^6.0.1
  responsive_navigation_bar: ^3.1.1
  shamsi_date: ^1.0.1
  uuid: ^3.0.5
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.1.0
  lottie: ^1.4.2
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2
  flutter_gradient_colors: ^2.1.1
  double_back_to_close_app: ^2.1.0
  flutter_custom_dialog: ^1.2.0
  awesome_dialog: ^2.2.1
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launch: ^0.3.0
  persian_number_utility: ^1.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

and the build.gradle:

```
  defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.instagram_clone_flutter"
        minSdkVersion 19
        compileSdkVersion 33
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by this: " if i downgrade to sdk version 2 or download it, it will again upgrade to version 3.2.0"? How do you downgrade and how does it upgrade by itself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555337/how-to-downgrade-my-sdk-version                        but after downgrading it will again update itselfe to version 3.2.0